# SOLVED: MagicMock and Flask-Request custom json for UnitTest

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

Good day,

I have the issue that I want to use a MagicMock like so;

```
m = mock.MagicMock()
m.mock_add_spec(spec=Request, spec_set=True)
#m.SOMEHOW SET THE JSON CONTENT SO m.get_json() works later on
```

So how could I return some sample json later on from the MagicMock object?

Solution:

```
class iMock(mock.MagicMock):
    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kw: Any):
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)

    def get_json(self):
        return {"node_id": 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

`m.json.return_value = {"my": "json"}` should work for you.

Comment: That returns really weird stuff. Anyways, I solved it by making a class inherit from MagicMock and giving it my own get_json(). Solved